# QEMU emulating two CPU archs

Tags: qemu, cpu, chroot, 64bit, x86

As I know, `x86_64` Linuxes are capable of running `x86` programs. I wonder if it would be possible to emulate it using QEMU.

I am using `proot` and hoping to `proot` into such said system.